# @ConditionalOnProperty: does it have an impact only on annotation specified below?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

Assume, that we have the following peace of  the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "scheduling.enable")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
public class AcmeServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AcmeServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Does `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation will enable\disable only `@EnableScheduling` or it will have an impact on `@EnableCaching` as well?

Did not find an answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a condition, such as `@ConditionalOnProperty`, is used on a class, it controls whether or not the whole class is processed. When it is used on a `@Bean` method, it controls whether or not the individual method is processed.

In the case of your specific example, if the condition matches, `AcmeServiceApplication` will be processed and therefore both scheduled and caching will be enabled and `@SpringBootApplication` will take effect by enabling auto-configuration and component scanning. If the condition does not match, `AcmeServiceApplication` will not be processed and therefore neither scheduling nor caching will be enabled and `@SpringBootApplication` will have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

`@ConditionalOnProperty` on `@SpringBootApplication` makes no sense and won't be processed. Regardless of `scheduling.enable` property presence `@EnableScheduling` and `@EnableCaching` will be applied.

As [Andy Wilkinson explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53345715/1602555) `@ConditionalOnProperty` is target for `@Configuration` and `@Bean` targets. `@SpringBootApplication` is something else entirely.